# add a pipeline variable of array type In ADO pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Is it possible to add a pipeline variable of array type in ADO pipeline? I’m trying to add a pipeline variable of array type with these values:

```
[
{ name: abc, id: 123 },
{ name: def, id: 456 }
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pipeline variable doesnot support complex type, all variables are stored as strings. You can try below workarounds depending on how you use the variable in your pipeline.

1, If you want to reference the variable in other task. You can define the variable as runtime parameters instead of pipeline variables. You can define the parameter like below:

```
parameters:
- name: Ids 
  type: object
  default: 
    - name: abc
      value: 123
    - name: efg
      value: 456
```

Then you can refer to the parameter using syntax like this :`${{parameters.Ids[0].name}}`

```
steps:
- powershell: |
     echo "${{parameters.Ids[0].name}}"
     echo "${{parameters.Ids[0].value}}"
```

2,  If you use the variable in a script task. You can save the value to json string. And convert to json object in the script. See below example:

First, Save the value to json string(`'[{"name":"abc", "value":111},{"name":"efg", value:222}]'`) to the pipeline variable:

[image]

Then, Convert to json object in the script task. See below example in powershell task:

```
steps:
- powershell: |
     $ids = $(ids) | convertfrom-json
     echo $ids[0].name
```

Answer (score 0):

No pipeline variables are strings. There is no way at the moment to have variable of complex type. Plese check this topic on [developer community - Variables in YAML pipeline are not allowing to define array](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/812728/variables-in-yaml-pipeline-are-not-allowing-to-def.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yaml variables have always been string: string mappings. Instead of using variable, you may consider [Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#parameters).

```
parameters:
- name: abc
  type: string
  default: 123
- name: def
  type: string
  default: 456
……
```